How to run the mouseover event after 3 seconds
I need to execute a function when the mouse pauses on an element for 3 seconds.
I tried to do this with the mouseover event, but the problem is that my function is triggered immediately when the mouse enters the element
 element.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
      myFunction()
   },3000)
  })

Is there a way to trigger the mouseover event after the user pauses on the element for 3 seconds?
Is there a better way?, please help me

300 is 0.3 seconds, not 3. Not the only problem you have tho. If you had correctly used "300", you probably would have the illusion that it "almost works": there would be a delay of 3 seconds between the moment the pointer hovers the element, and the call of "myFunction". But then "myFunction" would be call many times, instead of once. And it would be called even if in the mean time, the pointer had left the element.

Rather than mouseover, I'd probably use mouseenter since mouseover fires repeatedly as the mouse moves across the element. Then you can use mouseleave to cancel the timer if the mouse leaves the element before the three seconds are up.
Something like this:


const target = document.querySelector(".target");
let timer = 0;
target.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
        timer = 0;
        console.log("Timer fired");
    }, 3000);
    console.log("Timer started");
});
target.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = 0;
        console.log("Timer cancelled");
    }
});
<div>Not a target</div>
<div>Not a target</div>
<div>Not a target</div>
<div>Not a target</div>
<div class="target">Target </div>
<div>Not a target</div>
<div>Not a target</div>
<div>Not a target</div>



That example only handles a single element (because timer is a single variable), but if you need to handle multiple, you could maintain a WeakMap using the element as the key and the timer handle as the value. (A WeakMap so that if the elements are removed from the DOM at some point, the map entries for them don't stick around unnecessarily.)

To achieve that behaviour in your app, you need to combine mouseover and mouseout events.
The key issue is to reset the timer every time the cursor hovers over an element and leaves it.
let timeoutId;

element.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
//clear any previous timeout
clearTimeout(timeoutId);

//set a new timeout for 3 seconds
timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("3 seconds elapsed!");
    myFunction();
}, 3000);
});

element.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
// clear the timeout if the mouse leaves the element
clearTimeout(timeoutId);
});

